# How Hyper-V DNS resolution works and how to fix VM registration delay?

Tags: dns, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have created Virtual Switch in Hyper-V management console (Windows 10) connected to the internet via ICS and launched a virtual machine (Linux) connected to this switch. I named virtual machine `m1` in the Hyper-V console. When it is up and running, I ssh to the machine by the assigned address (192.169.137.226 in my case).

**Question:** I can see that `nslookup m1` (running from within the VM) returns correct IP address of the Virtual Machine guest host, which was assigned automatically (192.169.137.226 in my case). It was a big surprise, because I have not launched or configured any DNS on the host machine. Where is this DNS server running to respond to this hostname resolution correctly?

**Follow-up question:** However, DNS does not respond immediately after VM is created. Correct DNS record is "registered" in about 3 minutes after launching the VM. How can I remove this delay or at least reduce the lag time in the registration?